# Issue in setting up element value in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

I have a problem setting up a value of an element in **IE 8**.

```
document.getElementById("id28").value=" ";
```

Above code clears value for the element in **Mozilla Firefox 26.0** and **Chrome version 19**.
But the same doesn't work for **IE 8**. I have also tried with **IE 9** and **IE 10**, but no luck.

Can anyone please suggest any workaround or solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this `document.getElementById("id28").value="";`

Comment: You need to post a complete example (HTML + JavaScript) that actually reproduces the problem. Otherwise, the answer can’t be more specific than “you have an error in your code, outside the snippet you posted”.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the problem you have with IE8 first the element is not cleared but after I added the the site to trusted sites it works